# Causal past of future null-like infinity for a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, causality

I can't understand following statement from Carroll book

> [Future] event horizon can be equivalently defined as the boundary of $J^-(\mathcal{I}^+)$, causal past of future null infinity.

I made use of Penrose diagram and get the following[image: t].

I used the curly line to denote the boundary of light cones(their angle is preserved because of conformal transformation). Wouldn't $\hspace{2pt} \mathcal{I^-}$ be also considered as event horizon since it's the boundary of causal past of $\mathcal{I^+}$?

Also is the following statement correct: Event horizon is a null surface because it is boundary of the casual past as $\mathcal{I^-}$ is also a null surface, by definition?

Comment: Well, $\mathcal{I^+}$ is also a boundary.